# Carry a field in WebForm

Tags: webforms

I would like to carry a field (i.e. Name) entered on the 1st page of a multi-page WebForm and reflect that field on the Confirmation (Thank You) page.

How would I go about doing this?

I am using Drupal 7.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve it as follows:

- Copy webform-confirmation.tpl.php from /webform/templates and into your theme's template folder
- Rename it to webform-confirmation-{nid}.tpl.php to apply the template to a specific webform
- Make sure you clear Drupal's cache after placing or renaming the template file
- Add the following snippet

  ```
  include_once drupal_get_path('module','webform') . '/includes/webform.submissions.inc';
  $submission = webform_get_submission($node->nid, $sid);
  // All the submitted values will be here, access the necessary values from this object.
  // print_r($submission);
  ```

I tried this snippet, and it works. It was taken from [Print submitted data on confirmation page](http://drupal.org/node/1515548).

Comment: So we will get all user entered values here right ?

Comment: yes, we will get all the current submitted values in $submission object

Comment: So, {nid} pertains to the specific webform nid? Where do I add the snippet, in the renamed webform-confirmation-{nid}.tpl.php file?

Comment: yes, you can add code to webform-confirmation-{nid}.tpl.php. nid the unique nid of webform.

Comment: Thx, I only want to display one user entered field on the confirmation page. The field is name and was entered on the first page of the form. Basically, I want to say "Thank's for your submission name...."

Comment: Ok, set it up. Sorry to be a pain, still learning.How do I see the values in the confirmation page?

Comment: use above snippet, and use print_r($submission); this object contain the submitted value. print the necessary value from that object in your successfull message

Comment: Still don't see any values on the confirmation page, I'll have to play around with it. Thank You

Comment: I'm getting Notice: Undefined variable: name in eval() (line 8 of /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/website/dev.partnerportal.atlantisrail.com/modules/php/php.module(80) : eval()'d code).